# How do I define an Angularjs controller after a script has loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api

I am trying to "angularize" the code in [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/js) quickstart guide on how to use the google calendar api.

I have the following code. For now, I am just trying to have a page that says `true` if the user needs to be logged into google, and `false` if they already have.

```
<html ng-app="calApp">
<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module("calApp",[]);

        app.controller('calController',function calController($scope){
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                'client_id': 'asdfghjkl123456',
                'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
                'immediate': true
            }, function(authResult){
                if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                    $scope.needslogin = false;

                }else{
                    $scope.needslogin = true;
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="calController">
        {{needslogin}}
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that the gapi.auth.authorize part gives me an error because it attempts to run before `client.js` has loaded.

The expected way to solve this is using a callback function. So I attempted

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=defineController"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var app = angular.module("calApp",[]);

    function defineController(){
        app.controller('calController',function calController($scope){
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                'client_id': 'asdfghjkl123456',
                'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
                'immediate': true
            }, function(authResult){
                if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                    $scope.needslogin = false;

                }else{
                    $scope.needslogin = true;
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

but now I get an error because the controller is not defined when `<body ng-controller="calController">` attempts to run.

Any tips on how to properly do this would be appreciated.

Comment: what specifically is the  first error? That script should have loaded well before controller ever runs

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'authorize' of undefined
        at new calController (angularindex.html:12)
        at Object.invoke (angular.min.js:41)
        at R.instance (angular.min.js:89)
        at m (angular.min.js:65)
        at g (angular.min.js:58)
        at g (angular.min.js:58)
        at angular.min.js:58
        at angular.min.js:20
        at m.$eval (angular.min.js:145)
        at m.$apply (angular.min.js:145)`

Comment: I dont get it .. scripts are loaded in synchronous fashion so i dont know why your facing trouble. Can you paste the error ?

Comment: Do you see the error pasted in the above comment?

Comment: I'm not sure why, but for some reason, there are a lot of stackoverflow questions about loading the google api and all of the answers say to use ?onload to solve them. But I don't know how you would do that in this scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define your controller after bootstrap

try

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=gapiBootCallback"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var gapiBootStrapper = {}; // an object that you can attach a callback function to in the controller

    var app = angular.module("calApp", []).constant('gapiBootStrapper', gapiBootStrapper); // Passing it into Angular as a constant is not necessary but stop us using global from within a controller

    function gapiBootCallback() {
        gapi.auth.authorize({
            'client_id': 'asdfghjkl123456',
            'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
            'immediate': true
        }, function (authResult) {
            if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                gapiBootStrapper.callback(false);
            } else {
                gapiBootStrapper.callback(true);
            }
        });
    }

    app.controller('calController', function calController($scope, $timeout, gapiBootStrapper) {
        gapiBootStrapper.callback = function (needslogin) {
            $timeout(function () { // Use $timeout so we don't need to call $scope.$apply
                $scope.needslogin = needslogin;
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to manually bootstrap your app in the call back

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        var app = angular.module("calApp",[]);

        app.controller('calController',function calController($scope){
            gapi.auth.authorize({
                'client_id': 'asdfghjkl123456',
                'scope': 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly',
                'immediate': true
            }, function(authResult){
                if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
                    $scope.needslogin = false;

                }else{
                    $scope.needslogin = true;
                }
            });
        });
        var callback = function() {

           angular.bootstrap(document, ['calApp']);
        };           
    </script>
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=callback">  </script>

</head>

<body ng-controller="calController">{{needslogin}}
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by that? Sorry, I'm new to javascript and angular

Comment: You could define the angular module and controller at any point, unless you bootstrap the angular wouldn't run

Comment: ok, so I tried the code you posted, but now the body just literally shows `{{needslogin}}` instead of true or false

Comment: Still no dice. Not sure if this is supposed to happen or not, but when I attept to run `var el = angular.element('html');` in the console, I get the error `angular.js:2949 Uncaught Error: [jqLite:nosel] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.7/jqLite/nosel(…)`

Comment: I changed the post, but i think you you have a different error entirely,